# pager in EntityFieldQuery

Tags: paging, entities, database

I know  I can have pager with `db_select` as example

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->condition('type', 'article')
      ->fields('n')
      ->extend('PagerDefault')
      ->limit(30);
```

is this possible has pager with `EntityFieldQuery` ?